# How to Update to Revision using Subclipse SVN plugin?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

In subclipse, the Team > Update menu option performs an "svn update -r HEAD".

I want to run "svn update -r [revision number]" but can't find a menu option which will let me update to anything besides the HEAD revision.

Answer (score 10):

It is the "Replace With" menu option. It is not under "Team", but on the same level.

Answer (score 6):

Subclipse used to prompt but users complained.  We did not want to add two update options.  The easiest way to do it is just Team > Switch and do not change the URL. Switch and update are the same code paths within Subversion.  If you do not change the URL it is just behaving like update and the Switch dialog exposes all the options available.